# Partial view render on button click duplicating Header / Footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a back button on an application so a user can go back and change something that they may need to fix or update.  I am using this javascript:

```
    $(function () {
    $(':button').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).data('url'),
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                $('#step1').html(result);
            }

        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

and this code:

```
<input type="button" value="Back" id="back" class="btn btn-default cancel" data-url="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" />
```

What's happening is when I click my back button it renders the header / footer twice with what seems to be inside my '#step1' div.  How can i keep the header / footer form rendering twice?

Updated:

```
    $(function () {
    $(':button').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: $("#step1").load($(this).data('url')),
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                $('#step1').html(result);
            }

        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: are you sure it's not caused by the fetched HTML source (that means the `result` already contains the duplicated headers/footers)?

Comment: it might be, I just want to go back to the previous page, it takes me to that page, but doubles the header/footer.

Comment: Is the result the same when you use `$("#step1").load($(this).data('url'))`?

Comment: Yes, Updated original post with what i changed.

Comment: What I mean is, you replace the whole `$.ajax();` block with the single `$("#step1").load($(this).data('url'))` block to load your partial view directly to the div.

Comment: Still duplicates the header / footer in step1 div